# Pandas copy value from 1 row and paste into another row with same key

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas df like this:

```
ID  NAME  RELATED_TO   INCOME
1   BOB    JOHN          100
1   BOB    MARY
```

Basically Bob is related to John and Mary, but in the i/p data, Bob's income is only specified on 1 record. What is the most concise way of copying Bob's income into both records for Bob?

Comment: `df.groupby('NAME').transform('ffill')` ?

Comment: or `df.groupby('NAME').INCOME.transform('first')` just in case the empty row is first.